# how could i use a string variable in WinHttpOpenRequest?

Tags: c, string, winhttp

I write a proggram that makes HTTP requests by using winhttp of windows ,and I wanted to do that the user could fill some things like what site and path.
so how could i use a string to fill those forms?
for example

```
     hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"PUT", 
                                   L"/html", 
                                   NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                                   WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                                   0);
```

how could i use a variable instead of "PUT" or "/html"

Comment: Do you not know how to get input into a variable or are you asking something else? Is it because the strings are wide strings?

Comment: i know how to get input from user...but when i just send a string to the function it doesn't work...

Comment: @mosh - then what makes you think it's not worth including the code you already have? If you want help fixing something, you need to supply that something.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and especially [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Your variable has to be a wide character string, that is the only type that WinHttpOpenRequest will accept so instead of using narrow character input use wide character input (wscanf instead of scanf for example).